# java Parcel@e7a33b1: Unmarshalling unknown type of arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist, parcelable, parcel

I'm trying to use `Parcelable` to pass data in android and but I got an error in this line while I use it in the correct type I didn't know what I miss here.

Here is the object which had the problem in parceling:

```
ArrayList<SecondChildCategory> secondChildCategories;
   public ArrayList<SecondChildCategory> getSecondChildCategories() {
        return secondChildCategories;
    }

    public void setSecondChildCategories(ArrayList<SecondChildCategory> secondChildCategories) {
        this.secondChildCategories = secondChildCategories;
    }
```

Here the parcel constructor for reading data:

```
protected ChildCategory(Parcel in) {
    if (in.readByte() == 0) {
        id = null;
    } else {
        id = in.readInt();
    }
    image = in.readString();
    softDelete = in.readString();
    if (in.readByte() == 0) {
        productCategoryId = 0;
    } else {
        productCategoryId = in.readInt();
    }
    createdAt = in.readString();
    updatedAt = in.readString();
    parentCategoryID = in.readString();
    backgroundColor = in.readString();
    name = in.readString();
    secondChildCategories = in.readArrayList(SecondChildCategory.class.getClassLoader()); // error reported here 
    hasChild = in.readByte() != 0;

}
```

and here how I write it:

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeInt(id);
    parcel.writeString(image);
    parcel.writeString(softDelete);
    parcel.writeInt(productCategoryId);
    parcel.writeString(createdAt);
    parcel.writeString(updatedAt);
    parcel.writeString(parentCategoryID);
    parcel.writeString(backgroundColor);
    parcel.writeString(name);
    parcel.writeList(secondChildCategories);
    parcel.writeByte((byte) (hasChild ? 1 : 0));

}
```

I got an error:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@e7a33b1: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7143535 at offset 372

on this line of code:

```
secondChildCategories = in.readArrayList(SecondChildCategory.class.getClassLoader());
```

Comment: The way you read int is not correct. If you have `writeInt` call then you should have the corresponding `readInt` call and nothing else (if you call `readByte` first then the data position moves and next call to `readInt` reads incorrect bytes). What do you want to achieve with `if (in.readByte() == 0)` condition?

Comment: I got an error for int values and solved it this way as I remember

Comment: btw, I remove this if and your answer is working thanks too much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use other methods to write and read list of `Parcelable`s:

1. use [`writeTypedList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeTypedList(java.util.List%3CT%3E)) for writing into `Parcel`

   parcel.writeTypedList(secondChildCategories);
2. use [`createTypedArrayList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#createTypedArrayList(android.os.Parcelable.Creator%3CT%3E)) for reading from `Parcel` (alternatively [`readTypedList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#readTypedList(java.util.List%3CT%3E,%20android.os.Parcelable.Creator%3CT%3E)) can be used)

   secondChildCategories = in.createTypedArrayList(SecondChildCategory.CREATOR);

Hope that helps.